# How to use reCaptcha on Symfony2 without FormBuilder

Tags: symfony, recaptcha

How to use ReCaptcha in Symfony2 without using the formBuilder? 

The bundles add the Captcha in a form using :

```
<?php

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    // ...
    $builder->add('recaptcha', 'ewz_recaptcha');
    // ...
}
```

But I never used the form builders for my views, how can I generate the captcha inside a controller and render it inside a template ?

Please help me.

Comment: Trying to use a Recaptcha form type without the form system will not work well.  I'm sure the form type is a simple wrapper.  Study the underlying recpatcha api to see how to use it directly.

Comment: Hi @Sekai, any solution? I am looking for this too.